# Android glitch opening app with full screen and list views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-fullscreen

I have configured my application and activities to work on full screen mode, but I'm finding with  a problem  I can't solve.

When my App starts up it goes from a  loading screen  to home screen, everything ok, but If I press "home" button and comeback to my App (no loading screen now, app it's started) then the layout is displaced by the status bar, and my bottom bar is cut. This effect lasts like 0.5-1 sec.

This also happens when a heads up notifications shows up.

[image]

My research points to listviews or  similiar views, like viewpager.
It just happened on my  activities with listviews, then I changed my activity to manage fragments  on a view pager, tried  again and now happens in every  single fragment, I mean my 3rd page is a simple fragment  and it didn't happen on that one, but now with  view pager it does.

I have all my activies with the same theme on manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".OpenActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
</style>
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navbar_space" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_fragment"
        android:name="es.udc.psi1516.pickapp.navbar.NavBarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navbar_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have some code on my MainActivity.java to hide status bar:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideSystemUI();
}

// This snippet hides the system bars
public void hideSystemUI() {
    int newUiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
}
```

And it only happens when you enter the App from App Icon, if you comeback from android task view it works nice. I gave up but if you have any ideas I would try anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I have found the solution.

I have had to remove the fullscreen property from xml styles, that was applying some internal states that broke my app screen.

And now I have to manage the state just in code.

1. Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` so my layout doesn't leave extra  space for status bar.
2. Remove `android:windowFullscreen` from style, now it looks like this:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Change code of flags to override current state on `onResume()`, I was adding flags to current state, don't ask me why, probably some copy-paste fail:

   ```
   private void hideSystemUI() {
       int newUiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
           View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
       getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
   }
   ```